# firstOrCreate add record only if date is different

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm trying to add a record only if `created_at` column contains a different date, so I don't need to check for hour and minutes, but only for year, month and day.

What I did is:

```
$currentDate = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
$ret = Configuration::firstOrCreate(
    [
        'user_email' => $request->input('user_email'),
        'created_at' => $currentDate
    ],
    [
        'price' => $request->input('price'),
        'data' => $json_code,
        'encoded_data' => base64_encode($json_code),
    ]
);
```

unfortunately, this code doesn't seems to work, the record is always added.
I suspect that laravel is doing the check on the hours and minutes also.

Is there a way to use `firstOrCreate` to add a record checking only `Y-m-d`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using `firstOrCreate`, don't pass a `created_at` attribute as this is always created with HH::MM::SS, you can make a new column on DB with `date` (YYYY-MM-DD) type to compare it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Configuration::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')) 
 ->firstOrCreate(
 [ 
   'user_email' => $request->input('user_email'), 
 ] , 
 [ 
   'price' => $request->input('price'), 'data' => $json_code, 
   'encoded_data' => base64_encode($json_code)
 ]);
```

Comment: I get "Illegal offset type"

Comment: When it will try to create a new model, one of the attribute will be `DATE(created_at)` which is invalid => illegal offset

Comment: I did edit it can you try now